# Remove in linux

Tags: linux, shell

hey so I have some code for the question bellow but I am stuck its not working and I don't really know what I am doing.

This script should remove the contents of the dustbin  directory. 
If the -a option is used the script should remove ALL files from the dustbin.
Otherwise, the script should display the filenames in the dustbin one by one and ask the user for  confirmation that they should be deleted

```
#!/bin/sh

echo " The files in the dustbin are : "
ls ~/TAM/dustbin

read -p " Please enter -a to delete all files else you will be prompted to delete one    by one : " filename

read ans
if ["filename" == "-a"]
cat ~/TAM/dustbin
   rm -rf*
else
   ls > ~/TAM/dustbin
for line in `cat ~/TAM/dustbin`
do
   echo "Do you want to delete this file" $line
   echo "Y/N"
   read ans
   case "ans" in
      Y) rm $line ;;
      N) "" ;;
esac
```

EDITED VERSION

```
 if test ! -f ~/TAM/dustbin/*
then
echo "this directory is empty"
else
for resfile in ~/TAM/dustbin/*
do
   if test -f $resfile ; then
   echo "Do you want to delete $resfile"
   echo "Y/N"
   read ans
   if test $ans = Y ; then 
   rm $resfile
   echo "File $resfile was deleted"
   fi
   fi
done
fi
```

this works however Now I get one of 2 errors either

line 4 requires a binary operator or line 4: to many arguments

Comment: You can use rm's `-i` option if you want user confirmation.

Comment: If you want to access a variable value, use `$`. Your "variables" in quotes are just strings, so: `"ans"` -> `$ans` and so on

Comment: For future posts, note that http://unix.stackexchange.com/ is more suitable for this kind of question that Stack Overflow.

Comment: So I have changed my code to the what I edit above

Comment: You should temporarily put `#!/bin/sh -vx` in the first line of your script to debug it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see one obvious mistake:

```
rm -rf*
```

when it should be

```
rm -rf *
```

to be asked about every file deletion - add *-i* key

```
rm -rfi *
```

Answer (score 0):

Many problems here:

- A space missing before the `*` in `rm`. The space is needed so the shell can recognize the wildcard and expand it.
- Do you really want to remove all the files in the current directory? If not, specify the path `rm -rf /path/to/files/*` or `cd` into the directory, preferably with `cd /path/to/files || exit 1`.
- I do not understand the logic of the script. You show a dustbin, but if the user gives `-a`, you overwrite it with all the non-hidden files (`ls > dustbin`). Is that what you want?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, `case "ans" of` just matches a *string* "ans" to other strings, which is obviously false, you need `case $ans of` to get the value of variable `ans`. `if ["filename" == "-a"]` is also comparison between two strings, which is always false. The first parameter of a script can be accessed as `$1` (the second as `$2` and so on).

Please read `man 1 sh` to get the basics of shell programming (all of the above notes can be found there).